# A* search algorithms custom f(n)

Tags: java, graph, graph-algorithm, adjacency-matrix

I'm wondering if A* search is suitable for the following situation:

1. There exist adjacency matrix for graph G (m x n)
2. Blocked cell is marked by 0
3. Non-blocked cell is marked by some value (let's call this prize!)

The goal is to find a Path from start to end but given multiple options to move vertical/horizontal, always choose cell with the largest prize.

Would this mean that the f(n) = g(n) + h(n) check would differ than the regular A* algorithms? Or perhaps given multiple f(n)'s (neighbors) with the same minimum value, choose the neighbor with the highest cell-value?

Would that skew the A* algorithms accuracy?